# Clarification on Data Storage Model in Sales Cloud

Tags: data-storage

I note that [this help document](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_storage_allocation.htm) explains:

> For data storage, Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions are allocated the greater of 1 GB or a per-user limit. For example, a Professional Edition org with 10 users receives 1 GB, because 10 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 200 MB, which is less than the 1 GB minimum. A Professional Edition org with 100 users receives more than the 1 GB minimum, because 100 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 2,000 MB.

However, this explanation conflicts with the documentation provided in this [Sales Cloud Edition sell sheet](https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf) which includes the footnote:

> † All editions include a minimum of 1 GB of data and 11 GB of storage shared by all users. Additional data storage is available on a per-org basis for each edition.

Is someone able to clarify what the actual model is?

- Is it 20MB per user with a minimum of 1GB or is it 11GB?
- How does the incremental storage model work for "additional data storage"? Do you purchase in 1GB increments and is this shared across all users?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that is a typo, they left out the word "File", to distinguish between Data storage and File storage. See reference:
https://www.shellblack.com/data/storage/